# Request header field X-CSRF-TOKEN is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Tags: laravel, vue.js, embed, axios

I'm making a get request to embed.rock using vue and axios.

```
axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: 'https://api.embed.rocks/api?url=' + this.url,
  headers: {
      'x-api-key': 'my-key'
  }
})
```

When I use a CDN to get vue and axios with an inline script my code works fine and I get a response back.

When I reference the installed vue and axios scrpts with an external script the code no longer runs and I get the following error:

> Failed to load https://api.embed.rocks/api?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DJ6PD_jBtU0&t=4s: Request header field X-CSRF-TOKEN is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

When I click on the error in the console it just brings me to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Laravel is setting a global configuration to include automatically the `X-CSRF-TOKEN` in the headers of the request in your `bootstrap.js` file.

```
let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');
if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}
```

Therefore, if you want to remove the token, you can achieve it like this:

```
var instance = axios.create();
delete instance.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'];

instance({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'https://api.embed.rocks/api?url=' + this.url,
    headers: {
        'x-api-key': 'my-key'
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've made the changes to my code and am still getting the exact same thing.

Comment: @user3325126 Are you sure? I've tested it and it seems to be throwing `X-Requested-With`. You can remove that from the headers as well.

Comment: Removing both did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

the problem is that by default the CSRF Token is register as a common header with Axios so
to solve this issue :

1- replace these lines in bootstrap.js

```
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf- 
token');
}
```

by this line

```
window.axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
```

2- install qs module by npm ..... using thie link : https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs

3- define const of qs like below :
    const qs = require('qs');

4- use axios by defult like this :

```
axios.post('your link here ',qs.stringify({
  'a1': 'b1',
  'a2 ':'b2'
}))
.then(response => {alert('ok');})
.catch(error => alert(error));
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution!